# When using df.drop in pandas make the index of rows shift

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a program where I take a random value find coordinates that are similar in distance to them add them to a group and remove them from the Dataframe.

So assuming I have the list of these coordinates

[image]

They should be grouped so that index

- 0 and 1 are together
- 2 and 4 are together
- 3 is alone

The issue im running into is that the initial index is chosen at random for the count of rows using

```
randInt = random.randint(0, count_row - 1)
```

and when I remove a coordinate point from the Dataframes it doesn't shift the others up like the following picture.

[image]

I am currently deleting the points using the following commands.

The random index chosen is added to a list then removed from Dataframe using

```
df.drop(current, inplace=True)
```

Then if a point is within a certain distance it is added to the list and removed using (where index is the index of the point in the Dataframes when looping through)

```
df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

So my question is, how can I make it so that when a point its removed it shifts the Ids up with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to reset index

`df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Thank you very much, it was something as simple as that that had me stuck for awhile!